# IBM App ID customization / branded UI

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, app-id, ibm-appid

I've started using App ID to manage customers in my node app. I have followed the samples that are available in GitHub. However, I do not see any guide or sample in how to customize it to interact with my domain. I do not use the default routes (https://appid-oauth.eu-gb.bluemix.net) as they appear in the sample images exposed in: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/new-app-id-let-users-sign-sign-apps-email-password/

There is one sample for doing it in Android (https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/01/use-branded-ui-user-sign-app-id/) but not in Node.js and iOS.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see the default route each time the default self-service UI is being used (sign up and forgot password).

Currently you can customize only the sign-in screen.
The sign-in button should call the “*signinWithResourceOwnerPassword*” API.
The sign-up button should call the “*launchSignUp*” API.
The forgot password should call the “*launchForgotPassword*” API.

All APIs and sample of use can be found in our SDK’s Readme.

Android:https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-android#managing-cloud-directory-with-the-android-sdk

IOS: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-swift#managing-cloud-directory-with-the-ios-swift-sdk

Node: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-serversdk-nodejs#cloud-directory